# Empty Excel file when opening it from OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

Code I've tried to open the file:

```
sfilename = "https://url"
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlsheet = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename, ReadOnly:=True)
```

and with

```
Set xlsheet = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename, ReadOnly:=True)
```

This opens a file (tested the URL a few times) but is empty, completely blank.

Code I've also tried:

```
sfilename = "https://url"
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")
Set xlsheet = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sfilename, ReadOnly:=True)
```

This way the document doesn't open (as far as I can see, maybe in the background) but getting Range("A1").Value returns 'empty'.

When I try the URL on the browser the file looks fine.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. A weird issue appears after testing when re-opening excel, it says it has an unsaved document dated 1/1/1601 at 2:00.

Answer (score 2):

`Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`

creates a new instance of Excel, but that instance will not be visible until you run:

`xl.Visible = True`

So the file likely did open (unless you got an error?), but you can't see it.

If you check in Task Manager you may see the instances you already opened.

Comment: The problem is not "not seeing the file", the problem is that I open it and is empty.

I want to open an excel file from another and get some data from it, this way I open it but I get nothing :S

Comment: I've never had any problems opening Excel files from SharePoint/OneDrive using `Workbooks.Open` and passing in a URL.

Comment: Try pasting the URL into the Excel file open dialog and see if it opens from there

Comment: As I said in the original post "When I try the URL on the browser the file looks fine"

But nevermind, I found another way to do this; I don't see how to close / cancel the question though.

Comment: @Jordi  so how you did it?

Comment: @Jordi Did you have any success in solving this issue?

Comment: In my case, it was a URL problem. I had to delete everything after "*.xlsx" then it worked. Initially, it was "*.xlsx?blahblah"

Comment: @Thoughtful_monkey ; I couldn't solve the issue so I re-though the whole process and did it in a totally different (and more convoluted ) way :/